# Unable to select ID from DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

```
public List<int> GetAllId()
{
     List<Checksin> list=DBContext.Checksins.Where(e=> e.Checkout_ID==null).Select( e=> e.Customer_Service_ID).ToList();
     return list;
}
```

getting error

> cannot implicitly convert `"System.collection.Generic.list<int>"` to
>   `system.collection.generic.list<HotelDB.Checkin>`

Comment: Customer_Service_ID is apparently an int. Change your List<Checkin> to List<int>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return type us wrong in the query. You are trying to convert list of integer to list of check in.

```
List<Checksin>
```

Please change this to

```
List<int>
```

or use var